# If multiple checkboxes selected - change innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am creating a reacting quiz that changes based on the answer you have selected using PHP and Javascript.

This is the working example of the radio button script that changes the innerHTML based on what answer you have selected. Using PHP to write the value as 'AQN20'

```
        $(function () {
            $("input[name=AQN2]:radio").click(function () {
                    if ($('input[value=AQN20]:checked').val()) {

                        document.getElementById("MCA2").innerHTML = "this is right";
                    } 

                    else {
                        document.getElementById("MCA2").innerHTML = "this is wrong";
                    }
            });
        });
```

I am trying to replicate the same behaviour for checkboxes but consider multiple answers.

So, I have a PHP array where you type your answers.

```
$multipleCheckboxOptions = array(
        'Option A',
        'Option B',
        'Option C',
        'Option D'
        );
```

I then create each answer as a checkbox option and assign the arrays Key to the Value. So in the example directly below, this would be the first option in the array (outputted HTML example).

`<input type="checkbox" name="AQN1" class="checkbox Q1" value="0" id="0mcq">`

I then have another array where you can select what the correct answers are.
`$correctAnswerNumber = array(0,2)`
In this instance, answer 1 and 3 would be the correct answers.

Below is where I am currently stuck for the checkbox on behaviour using PHP,

```
        $(function () {
            $("input[name=<?php echo $uniqueIDAnswer ?>]:checkbox").click(function () {

                    if ($('input[value=<?php echo $correctAnswerNumber?>]:checked').val()) {

                        document.getElementById("CA<?php echo $mcanumber?>").innerHTML = "<?php echo $correctAnswerDescriptionAnswer ?>";
                    } 

                    else {
                        document.getElementById("CA<?php echo $mcanumber?>").innerHTML = "<?php echo $incorrectAnswerDescriptionAnswer ?>";
                    }
            });
        });
```

I need the [value=] tag ($correctAnswerNumber) to output 0 && 3

`'input[value=<?php echo $correctAnswerNumber?>]:checked'`

I hope I have explained this clearly enough! Sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: Please share the html part for better understanding

Answer (score 0):

It should be RadioButtonGroup instead of CheckBoxGroups and also create one more variable which is call as Answer and where the true answer is placed set that radio button as Answer and make a logic answer is selected it will be ur right answer